# <omp.h> library isn't found in the GCC version (4.2.1) in Mavericks

Tags: gcc, openmp, osx-mavericks

I  have a problem with GCC. I want to update it to a new version, from the 4.2.1, to program with parallel programming. However, in this version there is no library . How can I download an updated version?

The error that the terminal give me is:

```
omp_hello.c:11:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Your problem is the same as [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321988/error-enabling-openmp-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-and-clang-errors).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried to do that tutorial ( downloading the files and do the installation ) but for now it doesn't seems work. But i will try again. ( that tutorial isn't for maverick, maybe there is something different ). If i try a solution i will write it here for others.

Comment: The tutorial is perfectly valid for Mavericks. I compiled GCC 4.8.2 on my Mavericks system by following it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. download gcc-4.9-bin.tar.gz download  or newer from
   http://hpc.sourceforge.net/:
   http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/hpc/gcc-4.9-bin.tar.gz
2. cd to your downloads folder and un-gzip
   the archive `gunzip gcc-4.9-bin.tar.gz` (Google Chrome would do that
   automatically)
3. in the same folder run `sudo tar -xvf gcc-4.9-bin.tar -C /` - this will place new executable to /usr/local/bin
4. add the following to ~/.bash_profile: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
5. open new terminal and run `which gcc`. This should point to `/usr/local/bin/gcc`

Comment: just to add something some people may need:                                                  1. don't forget "/" in step 3.                                                                          2. if u d not know how to add that path in step 4, check this post http://superuser.com/questions/678113/how-to-add-a-line-to-bash-profile

Comment: hey, I did all the steps and after typing which gcc, it does show it is in usr/local/bin and 'gcc -v' gives the 4.9 version. However, when I used 'make' to install a program that requires omp.h, it still shows "fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found" and it is still the clang version. Does it have anything to do with the "make" file. When I type 'which make', it is /usr/bin which is where the gcc 4.2 located but gcc 4.9 is at /usr/local/bin/.

Answer (score 5):

I got this message when I tried to reinstall GCC via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

> GCC has been built with multilib support. Notably, OpenMP may not work:
>     https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60670
>
> If you need OpenMP support you may want to
>     brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib

So, if you have Homebrew installed, you could try (on the terminal):

```
brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
```

This process may take [a while](https://superuser.com/questions/788256/brew-install-gcc-mac-os-10-9-mavericks) !

Answer (score 2):

According to this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25735227) on apple's forums, try using [gcc-4.9-bin.tar](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) .

First install the gcc-4.9  and type `"xcode-select --install"` on your terminal.

Then, use `"/usr/local/bin/gcc "` as compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it just adding aliases to .bash_profile

```
# Aliases in order to use brew gcc
alias gcc='gcc-5'
alias cc='gcc-5'
alias g++='g++-5'
alias c++='c++-5'
```