# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 installing Fatiando (Python Package)

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda

I am trying to install fatiando, a geophysical modelling package for Python.
I have a Mac with OS X v10.9.5. I am getting all the dependencies for Fatiando (via Anaconda) by following the recommended installation  suggested on the [package site](http://fatiando.readthedocs.org/en/releases/install.html). I have Xcode installed.

I get a list of warnings and a final error message:

```
    fatiando/gravmag/_polyprism.c:349:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found

    #include "omp.h"

             ^

    1 warning and 1 error generated.

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "//anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/folders/32/mwq0jhwd3dx7vjqmm8hkljp80000gn/T/pip-QFjo6d-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/32/mwq0jhwd3dx7vjqmm8hkljp80000gn/T/pip-CY4vyX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/32/mwq0jhwd3dx7vjqmm8hkljp80000gn/T/pip-QFjo6d-build
Macintosh-5:fatiando matteoniccoli$
```

The full Terminal output (1100+ lines) can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pnznpm8ud29c2bi/Terminal_output?dl=0).

I already contacted the developers, this does not seem to be a Fatiando issue.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE, March 15**

When I first posted this I did not have Xcode, then I downloaded the latest Xcode from Apple store. Tried again, got the same message. Then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780323/1034648) and downloaded gcc from [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer), and installed directly. When I type on terminal: `gcc --version`, I get this: `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)`
After that, though, I still get similar messages. Following another stackoverflow lead, I tried to install setuptools from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads) 
using  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python 
Now I get a different error (at the end again of a long output) when I try to install fatiando:

```
fatiando/gravmag/_polyprism.c:349:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found

    #include "omp.h"

             ^  

    1 warning and 1 error generated.  

    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------

    Command "//anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/32/mwq0jhwd3dx7vjqmm8hkljp80000gn/T/pip-build-m1ieVO/fatiando/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/32/mwq0jhwd3dx7vjqmm8hkljp80000gn/T/pip-9wI6Z7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/32/mwq0jhwd3dx7vjqmm8hkljp80000gn/T/pip-build-m1ieVO/fatiando
```

Someone from a forum asked me by email:
Re Fatiando, did you install Xcode command line tools? Eg see this
http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

But when I try to verify tI’ve successfully installed Xcode Command Line Tools as suggested there, I get this, so I assume it was not the issue:

```
-bash: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools: is a directory
```

**UPDATE MARCH 16**
Tried solution suggested by Leo Uieda.

pip install `--upgrade https://github.com/fatiando/fatiando/archive/kill-omp.zip` went without a problem, but

`pip install --upgrade https://github.com/fatiando/fatiando/archive/master.zip` gets me back at square 1:

```
...
...    
fatiando/gravmag/_polyprism.c:349:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found

        #include "omp.h"

                 ^

        1 warning and 1 error generated.

        error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

        ----------------------------------------
        Rolling back uninstall of fatiando
```

Comment: Please include the terminal output in the question, not on an external page.

Comment: It is extremely long  Ismail, more than 1100 lines. Should I include the whole thing? I am not sure what's relevant and what is not.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990296/how-to-include-omp-h-in-os-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem with the Fatiando install, specially on Windows and Mac. OpenMP was introduced in [PR 106](https://github.com/fatiando/fatiando/pull/106) for the `fatiando.gravmag` forward modeling modules. It was easy to implement (just replace a `range(ndata)` with a `prange(ndata)`) and was resulting in 1.5-2x speedup over sequential execution. Also, the parallel execution was automatic. So it seemed like a good trade-off at the time ("Just install an extra dependency? What could go wrong?").

The problems began when the Anaconda `gcc` and the default Mac `gcc` didn't come with OpenMP. So Windows users had to install an extra dependency (in a very specific order, like a satanic ritual) and Mac users had to fend for themselves.

OpenMP and compiled Cython modules are being removed from Fatiando ([#169](https://github.com/fatiando/fatiando/issues/169)) in preference of `multiprocessing` and `numba`. This would make it a pure Python package (no compilation necessary) and most of the install issues should be resolved.

In the mean time, [PR 177](https://github.com/fatiando/fatiando/pull/177) removes the OpenMP requirement  from the Cython modules. This should fix your current install problems. To get the changes right away, you can install the version from the `kill-omp` branch by running:

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/fatiando/fatiando/archive/kill-omp.zip
```

If the above command doesn't work, it means that the pull request has been merged into the main branch of the project (master). If that's the case, you can install the latest version from the `master` branch:

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/fatiando/fatiando/archive/master.zip
```

These changes will be included in the future v0.4 release. Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: I'll try this evening

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that you should run both commands. Just use the first one for now. In the future, this will get merged into the master branch and will become part of the package officially. You should uninstall Fatiando first, just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

(It would be useful to know which version of gcc you are using.)

gcc did not ship with [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) prior to v4.9.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340117/omp-h-library-isnt-found-in-the-gcc-version-4-2-1-in-mavericks) could help you update gcc it using xcode.

Comment: When I type on terminal: gcc --version, I get this: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00) - see my update to the question.

Comment: suggestions in 2nd and 3rd answer there do not work. I followed the 1st anser to this tutorial https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/ will be trying it.