# C OpenMP parallel for loop is not running on more than one thread

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

I am trying a simple example of Open MP, to parallelize a for loop, but I cannot see that the for loop is being executed on more than one core.

Here is the C program:

```
#include </usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/5.1.0/include/omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for(n = 0; n < 10; n++)
            printf(" Thread %d: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), n);

        printf("Number of threads: %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
    }
    printf("Total number of cores in the CPU: %ld\n", sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN));
}
```

The above code is very similar to [this example](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LoopDirectiveFor).

When I execute this program and print out the total number of threads being used by it (by default it should be the total number of CPU cores), I find the result `1`. Here is the output:

```
10:pavithran$ gcc -fopenmp openMPExample.c -o openMPExample.o
10:pavithran$ ./openMPExample.o 
 Thread 0: 0
 Thread 0: 1
 Thread 0: 2
 Thread 0: 3
 Thread 0: 4
 Thread 0: 5
 Thread 0: 6
 Thread 0: 7
 Thread 0: 8
 Thread 0: 9
Number of threads: 1
Total number of cores in the CPU: 8
10:pavithran$
```

Why is it that I do not find the numbers being printed by different threads? Why is it that the total number of threads is always 1? Someone please help me in getting the parallel for loop to work.

PS: The first "#include ..." statement contains the explicit path because the simple form: `#include <omp.h>` [does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340117/omp-h-library-isnt-found-in-the-gcc-version-4-2-1-in-mavericks).

Comment: how many cores does your CPU have?

Comment: The CPU has 8 cores. I have edited the question to include this too. Thanks.

Comment: Try forcing the number of threads with: `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)`

Comment: I tried this... unfortunately, it doesn't seem to affect the output. The output is the same as in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are compiling your program with Apple's clang version of `gcc` that does not support OpenMP. This is why you get the output

```
$ gcc main.c -fopenmp
main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

when using

```
#include <omp.h>
```

as opposed to *(the montrosity)*

```
#include </usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.1.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/5.1.0/include/omp.h>
```

#### Using the Correct Version of `gcc`

**Note:** *Based on the include path I'm assuming use of [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install `gcc`. If that is not the case there is a section at the end on installing `gcc` via Homebrew with OpenMP support.*

Homebrew installs `gcc` as **`gcc-4.9`** or **`gcc-5`** (for both GCC 5.1 and GCC 5.2) depending on the version you have installed. It does **not** create a symlink for `gcc` in `/usr/local/bin` and so when you execute `gcc` from the command line you will be calling Apple's clang version. This is what we must correct for and there are a multitude of ways in which we can use the Homebrew version of `gcc` over Apple's clang version

1. Explicitly execute `gcc` via

   ```
   $ gcc-5 main.c -fopenmp
   ```
2. Create a symlink for `gcc` in `/usr/local/bin` with the following commands

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/bin
   $ ln -s gcc-5 gcc
   ```

   Now when you execute `gcc -v` you should see something similar to the below (providing your `$PATH` variable is set up correctly, see below, and you've installed `gcc` with OpenMP support via Homebrew, see below)

   ```
   $ gcc -v
   Using built-in specs.
   COLLECT_GCC=gcc-5
   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
   Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-5 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 5.2.0 --without-multilib' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --disable-multilib
   Thread model: posix
   gcc version 5.2.0 (Homebrew gcc 5.2.0 --without-multilib)
   ```
3. Create an alias for the Homebrew version of `gcc`. You can do this by adding a line similar to

   ```
   alias hgcc='gcc-5'
   ```

   to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. What is even better is to add it to a file called `.bash_aliases` and then include it in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` with

   ```
   [[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]] && . ~/.bash_aliases
   ```

   We would then execute it via `hgcc` as in

   ```
   $ hgcc main.c -fopenmp
   ```

#### Aside: Installing `gcc` with OpenMP support on OS X

To install `gcc` with OpenMP support the easiest route to take is via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). To do this you need to use the following command as per [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29109926/1552737)

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

or if you have already installed `gcc` via Homebrew use

```
brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
```

This installs `gcc` as **`gcc-4.9`** or **`gcc-5`** (for both GCC 5.1 and GCC 5.2) depending on the version you have installed. It does **not** create a symlink for `gcc` in `/usr/local/bin` and so when you execute `gcc` from the command line you will be calling Apple's clang version. You can verify this by running `gcc -v` which should produce a similar output to the below

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

#### Checking Path is Set Correctly

On (my Mac system at least) the default `$PATH` includes `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` as in

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If this is not the case for you you will need to edit your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This ensures that the Homebrew version of `gcc` will be found before any of the Apple versions, when we correct for Homebrew installing it as `gcc-4.9` or `gcc-5`.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable?
What would give you something like this?

```
 > OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./openMPExample.o
```

(BTW, having a binary which name ends with '.o' might not be such a good idea)

Comment: Thanks! That works... however, if there is a way of hiding `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8` somewhere in the source code or at least in the make file, that would be great...

Comment: Though your solution is an excellent quick fix, I'll vote for the other since it seems more of a permanent fix.