# library not found for -lgomp

Tags: c++, macos, openmp

I am trying a basic openmp program on mac osx. I am on Mavericks and have the latest Xcode.

```
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
        const int size = 256;
        double sinTable[size];

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int n=0; n<size; ++n)
                sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / size);

        // the table is now initialized
}
```

When I compile the code from terminal as `g++ Test.cpp -fopenmp`, I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How should I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The latest Xcode does not include gcc. g++ is a file that runs clang, which does not include OpenMP

Comment: @Mark Thanks. So how should I fix this?

Comment: See the duplicate but you need to install another compiler

Comment: The question has been addressed [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321988/error-enabling-openmp-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-and-clang-errors