# Compilation fails for OpenMP - Mac OS X 10.9.4

Tags: osx-mavericks, openmp

I followed Jason Parham's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321988/error-enabling-openmp-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-and-clang-errors/21789869#21789869) to enable openmp in my mac osx 10.9.4. I am stuck when I tried to make libomp_oss.

```
make complier=clang
clang: error: unknown argument: '-no-intel-extensions' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make[1]: *** [unstripped/libiomp5.dylib] Error 1
```

( I commented out line 450 & 451 in libomp_oss/tools/check-tools.pl.)

What should I do to enable openmp?

Thanks,
Rouse

EDIT: Changed compier=lang to compiler=clang

Comment: `make complier=lang`?  Not `clang`?

Comment: Should be `compiler=clang` as in the script provided in the linked answer. Also, note that you are not "enabling OpenMP" but rather building an entirely different compiler that supports OpenMP.

Comment: Apologies. It is compiler=clang. @Hristo - Thanks for the clarification. I am new to this and learning the terminologies.