# Includes not found for clang++ + OpenMP + stdlibc++

Tags: c++, macos, clang, openmp, std

I followed the excellent walkthrough on how to compile clang(++) with OpenMP support for Mac OS X found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321988/error-enabling-openmp-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-and-clang-errors/21789869#21789869). However, while compiling a simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

...I simply get:

```
$> clang2++ -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fopenmp -o openmp openmp.cpp 
openmp.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
```

My newly compiled clang project doesn't seem to include libc++ and even if the standard directories are included ("standard" afaik), i.e:

```
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

...it still doesn't work. Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: In gcc we use -L to specify the library directory implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully compiled clib++ by adding a missing step in the Clang / OpenMP build procedure.

On the Clang / OpenMP page (http://clang-omp.github.io/) it asks you to download the following:-

```
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/llvm
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/compiler-rt llvm/projects/compiler-rt
$ git clone -b clang-omp https://github.com/clang-omp/clang llvm/tools/clang
```

If you want to include c++11 support you should also download:-
    $git clone https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx llvm/projects/libcxx

One of the build parameters is LLVM_EXTERNAL_LIBCXX_SOURCE_DIR (defined in CMakeCache.txt) which expects libcxx in this location.

*Note. I had to make a slight modification to the build instructions referred to in Kyle Halladays OSX Mavericks instructions, replacing:
    ../configure --enable-optimized 
    with 
    ../configure --enable-optimized CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++

Answer (score 0):

ok you can include the directory that contain iostream 
clang2++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fopenmp -o openmp openmp.cpp -I /usr/include

if /usr/include contain iostream file

Comment: Thank you. The include files seems to be located at /usr/include/c++.

Comment: never mind but try and tell me until work done with you