# Installing openmpi on OS/X: clang error: library -lgomp not found

Tags: macos, clang, openmpi

I'm aiming to install openmpi 1.6.5 on my Macbook Pro, mountainlion 10.8.5,  by following the straightforward guidelines at:
https://wiki.helsinki.fi/display/HUGG/Installing+Open+MPI+on+Mac+OS+X
While configuring with 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin F77=gfortran FC=gfortran 
is successful,  "make all" fails with:

```
  clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp'
      CXXLD  vtfilter
    ld: library not found for -lgomp
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[7]: *** [vtfilter] Error 1
```

As a complete newbie, I'm stuck on this error... I read about it error here:
[Error enabling openmp - "ld: library not found for -lgomp" and Clang errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321988/error-enabling-openmp-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-and-clang-errors)
(sorry for the new thread on possibly the same issue--this website's instructions guided me to not post a new question as an answer to an old thread...)
I'm not sure if these fixes apply here (?)-- I've tried the ordering within $PATH, which had no effect.  Does this look like I have an issue with my compilers?  If there is more useful information I can post, please let me know.

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier if you simply disable building of the bundled VampirTrace library:

```
$ ./configure --enable-contrib-no-build=vt ...
```

If you still need to trace and profile your MPI applications, you could [download VampirTrace](http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/vampirtrace) and build it separately.