# brew install clang-omp not working

Tags: clang, openmp, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I need to compile a C++ code with OpenMP on my Mac. Unfortunately the default version of clang installed on the Mac (703.0.31) does not support OpenMP.
Therefore, I am trying to install the clang-omp package with brew (e.g., following [this](https://gist.github.com/fyears/59e67cf0f521bc199235) guide). The issue is that brew cannot find neither the libiomp, nor the clang-omp package:

```
$ brew install clang-omp
Error: No available formula with the name "clang-omp"
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I am wondering whether clang-omp is still provided by brew. Or am I doing something wrong? Any ideas?

Edit: If I do brew search I get the following:

```
$ brew search clang
clang-format           emacs-clang-complete-async
Caskroom/cask/openclonk-c54d917-darwin-amd64-clang
```

Thus, no evidence of clang-omp. Is it possible I have to change repository or something like this?

Comment: Have you updated the `brew` recipes by calling `brew update` first?

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes, I did it. Just to be sure, I have re-done it right now (I have updated Homebrew from 87173cb to 984ed83) but still clang-omp is not found (I get the same error above).

Comment: LLVM 3.8 and later should support OpenMP "out of the box". Therefore there should no longer be any need to have a specific, different, clang-omp...

Comment: You could use `gcc v6` to compile C++ with OpenMP. You can install with `brew install gcc --without-multilib`

Comment: @JimCownie How would you compile C++11 compliant `main.cpp` which uses OpenMP with LLVM please - what would be the full command-line?

Comment: you can reference to link http://macappstore.org/clang-omp/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can install llvm using brew since it now includes openmp.

```
brew install llvm
```

You can make a symlink if you want

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang /usr/local/bin/clang-omp
```

My makefile looks like this

```
CPP = /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -fopenmp
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib

example: example.c
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: It says `omp.h` doesn't exists. Is it possible if you could provide an example, will be very helpful as i'm struggling to get it work with openmp.

Comment: @PiyushChauhan If I run `make` using the makefile in the answer, it would run `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -fopenmp example.c -o example -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/include`

Comment: What is the optional symlink step for? `ln -s /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang /usr/local/bin/clang-omp`

Comment: The symlink is to put it in your path. I added the `-omp` to separate it from default `clang` and because it used to be called `clang-omp` in brew.

Answer (score 11):

Install a deleted formula

```
brew install homebrew/boneyard/clamp-omp
```

OR

```
brew tap homebrew/boneyard
brew install clang-omp
```

Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/1110414/install-a-deleted-homebrew-formulae/1110934#1110934

Then you need to set the environment:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp:$C_INCLUDE_PATH

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/!date!/include/libiomp:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/!date!/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Nice copy & paste of the deleted formula part from http://superuser.com/a/1110934/429046 without credit.

Comment: @coatless Sorry, I just want to help. Hope you won't mind.

Comment: Just give credit where credit is due, especially if you copy wording...

Comment: Also, you may wish to remove the <formula> in the first example in favor of clamp-omp

Comment: this doesnt work when you have to use an older command lines tools

Comment: I think this doesnt work anymore... We cant use brew tap anymore

Answer (score 8):

**clang-omp** has been **boneyarded**. See this commit: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/c57e30773:

clang-omp: migrate to boneyard

Functionality is now available as part of LLVM in Homebrew.
**So just install llvm**

Comment: I've just install `llvm` using `brew install llvm`. Still, the program I want to use ([LDSTORE](http://www.christianbenner.com/#)) is not working, stating `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libiomp/lib/libiomp5.dylib`. How do I make sure that it is properly loaded? Where do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP was officially included in the brew (before the method, either install llvm, or outdated clang-omp).

```
brew install libomp
```