# Installation issue "clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'" (macOS Sierra)

Tags: c++, r, macos

Have you ever face

```
"clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'"
```

issue when installing R packages (me is installing ChIPseeker)?

I'm using macOS Sierra and trying to install ChIPseeker via biocLite.

The error message is as below:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [coxph.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mgcv’
```

Thanks!
Kylie

Comment: Do you have OpenMP installed, e.g. `brew install clang-omp`

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks.

I could not install OpenMP through brew.

The error message is as below:
Error: No available formula with the name "clang-omp" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: see maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971394/brew-install-clang-omp-not-working