# openmp in MAC OS 10.12.6

Tags: macos, openmp

I tried to install openmp in OS 10.12.6 following the instructions given here
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-Install-OpenMP-on-Mac-10-11-6

but the simple command

> brew install clang-omp

did not work and I got the error

```
Error: No available formula with the name "clang-omp".
```

Then following the instructions contained here

[brew install clang-omp not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971394/brew-install-clang-omp-not-working)

I tried to reinstall llvm by doing

> brew reinstall llvm

and the installation was successful but I see no trace of omp. If I try to compile with g++ or gcc a simple program including `<omp.h>` and compiling with the -fopenmp flag I get

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

even if I checked that in other cases it has worked ([Enable OpenMP support in clang in Mac OS X (sierra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra)).

I've tried to look for openmp in mac port as well but I haven't managed to find it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here how to force Apple's clang to support OpenMP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230419/3419533

Comment: It seems that almost all existing solutions don't work anymore. `brew install gcc --without-multilib` doesn't work anymore either.

Comment: You just need to install llvm now. See [my answer to the question you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra).

Answer (score 3):

You need a recent version of llvm and libomp which you can get with

```
brew install llvm
brew install libomp
```