# dyld: Symbol not found: __ZdaPvm - Running KING on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bioinformatics, dyld, genetics

I'm having an issue running [KING](http://people.virginia.edu/~wc9c/KING/manual.html) on Mac OS X . It has to do with a dyld link error, I think. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

```
   > ./king -b ./ex/ex.bed
```

Returns:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZdaPvm
  Referenced from: /Users/gaelgarcia/Downloads/./king (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /Users/gaelgarcia/./king
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: normally a `dyld` error is a dynamic linker issue. in my experience, the problem lies in the compilation. 

what version of Mac are you using? did you compile KING from source? is it built with all of the requisite libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues trying to use [the provided precompiled Mac version](http://people.virginia.edu/~wc9c/KING/Mac-king.tar.gz).  I was able to get a running version built [from source](http://people.virginia.edu/~wc9c/KING/KINGcode.tar.gz) running the following in the unzipped source directory:

```
clang++ -L /opt/local/lib/libomp/ -lm -lz -O2 -fopenmp -o king *.cpp
```

having first installed **libomp** in the above directory. I use Macports, so I did this with

```
port install libomp
```

For Homebrew users, [the recommendation seems to be to simply install `llvm`, which now includes **openmp** support directly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39843038/570918)

---

**EDIT:** Having installed `llvm` via Homebrew (`brew install llvm`), the command that got KING properly built and running on my Mac OS 10.12 was:

`/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/bin/clang++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/include -L /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/lib -O2 -fopenmp -lm -lz -o king *.cpp`

Running the newly built executable with the example `.bed` file provided:

```
> ./king -b ../ex/ex.bed

KING 2.1.3 - (c) 2010-2018 Wei-Min Chen

The following parameters are in effect:
Binary File :    ../ex/ex.bed (-bname)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, merv. Can you elaborate on how you installed `libomp`?

Comment: Thanks. I just installed `llvm` as suggested, and updated my build command to: `clang++ -L /usr/local/Cellar/llvm -lm -lz -O2 -fopenmp -o king *.cpp`... but still get an error to do with `openMP` : `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'` . I'm not sure if I'm specifyng `-L`correctly.

Comment: @gaelgarcia, following [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39843038/570918), your line should be something like: `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/bin/clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/lib -fopenmp -lm -lz -O2 king *.cpp`.  Basically, you're going to use clang from the llvm you've just installed.

Comment: Can I PayPal you for a coffee please? It's working! Thank you so, so much. And I'm serious about the coffee. I'm editing your answer to make the solution clear for future sufferers.

BTW, in my case, `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/bin/clang++  -I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/lib` (note the extra 6.0.0 in all 3 paths) `-O2 -fopenmp -lm -lz` and `-o king *.cpp` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone like me looking for an answer years later, I managed to solve this problem by installing gcc with Homebrew.

```
brew install gcc
```

which includes libgfortran. Probably unnecessary, since I had dyld installed in Anaconda, but I found it was the easiest way to get King working on my mac.

Edit: I also had to set my `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my bash profile, as well, by going

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and adding

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/libgcc/
```

or wherever the dynamic library `libgcc_s.1.dylib` is when you search for it on your computer.