# OpenMP on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, gcc, openmp, homebrew

I installed the gcc compiler via `xcode-select --install` but the version installed is `4.2.1` then it isn't possible to use the OpenMp flag `-fopenmp` for compile the source code.

I tried to install the compile via `Homebrew` and link this to the gcc exported but it doesn't work. I tried to install gcc building the latest GNU release but after building the operative system asked me if I would install gcc using `xcode-select --install`.

Moreover, I follow the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467142/6608222) but I have this error:

> Error: No available formula with the name "clang-omp"

Is there any solution or suggestion I can follow to execute the OpenMP code on my Mac and on any unix-like device without having to install particular dependencies because in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39843038/6608222) there is a solution but the user can install dependencies?

Comment: You can use native clang compiler, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230419/3419533

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983933/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenMP code can be compiled with AppleClang on mojave. Xcode includes an openmp-aware preprocessor which must be invoked.

- You must have an omp installed; libomp is the most common. I have also used libiomp5.
- Adjust the flags in cmake to point to your openmp solution.:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="clang" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="clang++" -DOpenMP_C_FLAGS=-fopenmp=lomp -DOpenMP_CXX_FLAGS=-fopenmp=lomp -DOpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES="libomp" -DOpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES="libomp" -DOpenMP_libiomp5_LIBRARY="/opt/local/lib/libomp.dylib" -DOpenMP_CXX_FLAGS="-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp /opt/local/lib/libomp.dylib -I/opt/local/include" -DOpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES="libomp" -DOpenMP_omp_LIBRARY=/opt/local/lib/libomp.dylib -DOpenMP_C_FLAGS="-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp /opt/local/lib/libomp.dylib -I/opt/local/include"
```

Similar flags for libiomp5: See [this line](https://github.com/Benitoite/RTdeps/blob/77562270c92bbe6ae9fe604264abaa15e8eda40c/macbuildRT.sh#L187).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Richard answer, I was able to compile a project that uses OpenMP on Mojave. I'm adding this answer because some of his flags are currently wrong or useless.

```
-DOpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES "libomp"
-DOpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES "libomp"
-DOpenMP_C_FLAGS "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include"
-DOpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include"
-DOpenMP_omp_LIBRARY "/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib"
-DOpenMP_libomp_LIBRARY "/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib"
```

`libomp` was installed with `brew install libomp`.

Comment: Thanks! And don't forget to add this to your project:

find_package(OPENMP)
target_link_libraries(openmp PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)