# Clang OpenMP library not found

Tags: clang, openmp, clang++

I'm trying to build a program using OpenMP, but I'm not able to get clang to recognize the library. I'm using a newer version of clang:

```
λ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

And I'm on OS X 10.10.5. When I try compiling, this is the error message that I get:

```
λ clang++ -fopenmp src/maranj_NumberCheck.cpp
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I thought that OpenMP was included in Clang after 3.7, but I'm on 7.0.2, so I don't understand why I'm having this problem. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321988/error-enabling-openmp-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-and-clang-errors), but that is over 3 years old, and I think that OpenMP wasn't a part of Clang yet.

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

clang tries to link -fopenmp with libgomp by default, which probably is not available in your system. Try to link to libomp or libiomp5

```
-fopenmp=libomp
```

or

```
-fopenmp=libiomp5
```

Comment: Those give me `clang: error: unsupported argument 'libop' to option 'fopenmp='` and `ld: library not found for -liomp5`

Comment: @NateMara It should be libomp. Try a `sudo find / -name "libomp*"` or `sudo find / -name "libiomp*"` to see if the libraries exist in your system. If they don't you need to download and compile the library from [here](http://openmp.llvm.org/)